# JavaScript Clipboard app not working, need assistance

Tags: javascript, html, variables, clipboard, netlify

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <head>
        <title> Query to Clipboard JS Applet by Damien Lesser </title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
    function getQueryVariable(variable)
    {
    var query = window.location.search.substring(1);
    var vars = query.split("&");
    for (var i=0;i<vars.length;i++) {
           var pair = vars[i].split("=");
           if(pair[0] == variable){return pair[1];}
    }
    return(false);
    }
    if getQueryVariable('list') === null{
    var clip = getQueryVariable('clip')
    } else{
    //Nothing
    };
    function copyStringToClipboard (str) {
    // Create new element
    var el = document.createElement('textarea');
    // Set value (string to be copied)
    el.value = clip;
    // Set non-editable to avoid focus and move outside of view
    el.setAttribute('readonly', '');
    el.style = {position: 'absolute', left: '-9999px'};
    document.body.appendChild(el);
    // Select text inside element
    el.select();
    el.setSelectionRange(0, 99999); /* For mobile devices */
    // Copy text to clipboard
    document.execCommand('copy');
    // Remove temporary element
    document.body.removeChild(el);
    };
    copyStringToClipboard(clip);
    var alert1 = 'copied '
    var alert2 = ' to clipboard successfully'
    console.log(alert1.concat(clip.concat(alert2)));
    var para = document.createElement('p');
    para.innerHTML = 'Copied successfully!'
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

As you have probably guessed, I am new to JavaScript, and I am trying to make a tool that allows developers to open a url with a query string, for the query to then be used for the clipboard, in those few niche cases where you can’t use other methods, or don’t have enough experience. It is supposed to happen automatically, but it produces no results.
If you would like to test it out, or use this tool once I have completed development, just go to https://querytoclip.netlify.app/

and then add ‘?clip=’ (without quotes)
Beyond what I have asked for so far, it would be nice if someone could make my code more efficient, because I am no wizard...

Answer (score 0):

This may help you a little:

```
function getQueryVariable(variable) {
  var query = window.location.search.substring(1);
  var vars = query.split("&");
  for (var i = 0; i < vars.length; i++) {
    var pair = vars[i].split("=");
    if (pair[0] == variable) {
      return pair[1];
    }
  }
  return (false);
}
if (getQueryVariable('list') === null) {
  var clip = getQueryVariable('clip')
} else {
  //Nothing
};

function copyStringToClipboard(str) {
  // Create new element
  var el = document.createElement('textarea');
  // Set value (string to be copied)
  el.value = clip;
  // Set non-editable to avoid focus and move outside of view
  el.setAttribute('readonly', '');
  el.style = {
    position: 'absolute',
    left: '-9999px'
  };
  document.body.appendChild(el);
  // Select text inside element
  el.select();
  el.setSelectionRange(0, 99999); /* For mobile devices */
  // Copy text to clipboard
  document.execCommand('copy');
  // Remove temporary element
  document.body.removeChild(el);
};
copyStringToClipboard(clip);

const contentDiv = document.getElementById("content");
var paragraph = document.createElement('p');
const paragraphContent = document.createTextNode("Copied successfully!");

paragraph.appendChild(paragraphContent);
document.body.insertBefore(paragraph, contentDiv);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code has a number of issues, but beyond that, you are going to run into some issues trying to copy to the clipboard on page load.

For security reasons, many document.execCommand commands require a user interaction (like clicking on a button).  Copy is one such method.  You could add a button to the page, and use @CLiown response to get something working where the page opens and you click a quick "copy" button.

For more info, read:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/execCommand